# Do apples grow on trees in the Shinigami realm?

Tags: death-note

In the Shinigami realm, there are other apples, that taste like sand, according to Misa Amane. Do these apples grow on trees in the Shinigami realm?

I think they may rather grow on a plant, close to the ground, because of the sandy taste. But I'm not sure whether there really is ground in the Shinigami realm.

I've also heard that nothing grows in the Shinigami realm.

Is there anything known about this? In the anime, there are not much scenes from the Shinigami realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Death Note wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Apples)

> Apples from the Shinigami Realm look like shriveled green peppers and do not resemble normal apples at all. Misa gave a juicy human apple to Ryuk and in return he lets Misa have a bite of an apple from the Shingami realm which Ryuk was carrying with him at the time. Misa takes a bite of the apple and then spits it out in disgust saying that it "tastes like sand".[image: Shinigami Realm Apple]

It is not mentioned either in the anime or manga, whether these grow on trees or not.

It is mentioned though that

> Apples have become a very popular commodity or currency in the Shinigami Realm when Ryuk returns with an unknown quantity after the end of the series. In the manga one-shot, Midora bribes the Shinigami King with 13 apples she brought back from the human world in order to receive an extra Death Note, which she gives to C-Kira.